# How to change pointers of dynamically resized array?

Tags: c

I'm trying to increase a static array by doubling it dynamically in another array as soon as it is maxed. I planed on created new array with `malloc()`, then copy values over. Once done, I planned on deleting first array and then pointing first pointer to second?

```
float FirstArray[1];

if (first array is full) {
    float *TempArray = (float*) malloc (sizeof (float) * counter);
    for (loop) {
        TempArray[i] = FirstArray[i];
    }
    //I'm not sure how to point the static array to the dynamic one
    free(FirstArray);
    *FirstArray = &TempArray;
//i get this error with line above
//assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
}
```

Comment: That's ok, but FirstArray needs to be dynamically allocated initially also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstArray needs to be dynamically allocated as well:

```
int counter = 1;
float *FirstArray = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*counter);

if (first array is full) {
float *TempArray = (float*) malloc (sizeof (float) * counter);
for (loop) {
TempArray[i] = FirstArray[i];
}
free(FirstArray);
FirstArray = TempArray;
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should consider `realloc`, as this is exactly why it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Static array allocations are managed automatically: you do not need to (and should not) allocate it, so you should not free it as well. You cannot assign a `float * (pointer) to float[N]` (`N-elem` static array) because these are considered incompatible types by the compiler. (Static array is also zeroed on init to mention one more difference.)

So basically you have two choices: forget the name FirstArray, preserve its content under new name (SecondArray?). Nonsense.. Other way is to have dynamic array from the beginnings.

```
uint size = 4096;
double * array = ( double * ) malloc( sizeof( double ) * size );
```

Then copy could be unneccessary, so use realloc as  Richard and Oliver pointed out.

```
size <<= 1; /* double size */
array = ( double * ) realloc( ( void * ) array, sizeof( double ) * size );
```

Notice that input and output pointers of realloc might differ. If not, copy is spared.